# Kotlin convert json array to model list using GSON

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am not able to convert a JSON Array into a `GroupModel` array.  Below is the JSON I used:

```
[{
  "description":"My expense to others",
  "items":["aaa","bbb"],
  "name":"My Expense"
 },
 {
  "description":"My expense to others","
  items":["aaa","bbb"],
  "name":"My Expense"
 }]
```

and the `GroupModel` class is:

```
class GroupModel {
    var name: String? = null
    var description: String? = null
    var items: MutableList<String>? = null

    constructor(name: String, description: String, items: MutableList<String>) {
        this.name = name
        this.description = description
        this.items = items
    }
}
```

and trying the following code results in an `Exception`:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 
>   BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

The code:

```
var model = gson.fromJson<Array<GroupModel>>(inputString, GroupModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a `TypeToken` to capture the generic type of the array, and you need this to be the type that GSON sees as the target, instead of just `GroupModel::class` it is really a list of those.  You can create a `TypeToken` and use it as follows:

```
Type groupListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<GroupModel>>() {}.getType();
var model = gson.fromJson(inputString, groupListType);
```

Comment: what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603236/using-gson-in-kotlin-to-parse-json-array ? ?

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. This answer does not work. The below 2 answer works correctly.

Answer (score 27):

```
[{
  "description":"My expense to others",
  "items":["aaa","bbb"],
  "name":"My Expense"
 },
 {
  "description":"My expense to others","
  items":["aaa","bbb"],
  "name":"My Expense"
 }]
```

**Kotlin Code**

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val Model= gson.fromJson(body,Array<GroupModel>::class.java).toList()
```

**Gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Answer (score 15):

I have found a solution that is actually working on Android with Kotlin for parsing JSON arrays of a given class. The solution of @Aravindraj didn't really work for me.

```
val fileData = "your_json_string"
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val packagesArray = gson.fromJson(fileData , Array<YourClass>::class.java).toList()
```

So basically, you only need to provide a class (`YourClass` in the example) and the JSON string. GSON will figure out the rest.

The Gradle dependency is:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```